# Overloading and invoking functions automatically by down casting the parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I have a base class called **User**.

I have 2 derived classes from User called DerivedUser, OtherDerivedUser

I have the following code:

```
 User user = newUser.CreateUserByType();
 SendNewUser(user);
```

**I don't want to perform an if or switch** statement and then to perform a downcast to the derived types.

I just want to perform a call with one line statement.

```
 SendNewUser(user);
```

I want **clean code with a one-liner*.

This method according to the type will "know" dynamically which method to invoke.

I have 2 functions called SendNewUser which are overloaded by the derived type.

Is there a way invoke the correct function by downcasting to the right derived  class
(I don't want to explicitly cast)

```
   private static void SendNewUser(DerivedUser user){
       ...
      }

     private static void SendNewUser(OtherDerivedUser user){
       ...
      }
```

Comment: It's called Double Dispatch (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) and the easiest way to achieve it in C# (although not always preferable) is using `dynamic`

Comment: @haim770 you don't need double dispatch in C# 7. The same thing can be performed a lot easier with pattern matching.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Obviously, if you're willing to change your code (either with `if`, `switch` or compiler tricks of C# 7) you *will* achieve that. But as I see it, the OP wants the compiler/runtime to choose the correct method automatically. For that, you *do* need Double Dispatch.

Comment: @haim770 double dispatch isn't `automatically`. It involves a set of classes that end up calling one version or the other. There is a reason pattern matching is preferred over double dispatch wherever it's available

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Currently the correct method is not being chosen, neither on compile-time or runtime. The *easiest* way (that is closest to "automatically") to make the runtime invoke the correct method is by casting the argument to `dynamic` (`SendNewUser((dynamic)user)`). Using `if`, `switch` and other workarounds is much further than "automatically".

Comment: @haim770 a valid point would be that C# 7's pattern matching is incomplete, without strict validation *yet*. If you pass an unexpected type, it won't detect it, hence the need to throw in the `default` clause. Double displatch offers strict validation indirectly, but it does offer it. Other languages like F# do offer strict validation

Comment: One another option is to use strategy pattern and fabric method like CreateSenderByUserType

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with pattern matching in C# 7:

```
switch (user)
{
    case DerivedUser u:
        SendNewUser(u);
        break;
    case OtherDerivedUser u:
        SendNewUser(u);
        break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Where did that come from?");
}
```

You can use pattern matching with `if` as well, although it won't improve readability all that much in this case:

```
if (user is DerivedUser u) {
    SendNewUser(u);
}
else if (user is OtherDerivedUser u) {
    SendNewUser(u);
}
else {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Where did that come from?");
}
```

Comment: Can't help but love C#7

Comment: btw, no need for the switch statement, i wanted just to call SendNewUser(u);

Comment: The `switch` statement used is just a special kind of `if` statement, similar to the code in my answer. It is just a trick, nothing more.

Comment: @TalAvissar you can use two `if` statements but that won't result in less code. `switch` in this case is a lot cleaner

Comment: @PatrickHofman so are a lot of C# features. This isn't a simple trick or the equivalent to the old `if is`. Each case does specify a separate block, which is what allow the same variable name to be used. You don't have to check twice, once for the type check and once for the cast

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to do this automatically.

You have a few options:

1. Move `SendNewUser` into the `DerivedUser` and `OtherDerivedUser` class. In that way you can simply overload the method and you just need to call `user.SendNewUser()`.
2. Detect the type and call the appropriate method:

   ```
   public void SendNewUser(User user)
   {
       if (user is DerivedUser)
       {
           SendNewUserInternal((DerivedUser)user);
       }
       else if (user is OtherDerivedUser)
       {
           SendNewUserInternal((OtherDerivedUser)user);
       }
       else
       {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException("Wrong user type.");
       }
   }
   ```

As you can see, that option is quite error prone and needs work for every new derived class you introduce. I would stick with option 1 if you can.

Comment: Pattern matching ?

Comment: Only with C# 7, but yes, you can.

Comment: The OP didn't *specifically* exclude it. :P.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want to perform if or switch statement and then to perform a
>   downcast to the derived types.

Just add `dynamic` to the function argument:

```
User user = newUser.CreateUserByType();
SendNewUser((dynamic)user);
```

Also see this example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Base ba = new A();
        Do((dynamic)ba);
        ba = new B();
        Do((dynamic)ba);
    }

    public static void Do(A a)
    {
        System.Console.Write("A");
    }

    public static void Do(B b)
    {
        System.Console.Write("B");
    }
}

public class Base{}
public class A : Base{}
public class B : Base{}
```

Gives the output:

```
AB
```

Comment: I would advise against the use of `dynamic` unless you really can't. In this case there are quite some good options, which you can use instead.

Comment: There are a lot of other ways to do this without losing type checking

Comment: Like it. Readable and short than switch or strategy.
Also if add one more realisation Do(dynamic o) { Do(o) } we wouldn't write (dynamic) every where, just call Do(ba);

Comment: @gabba readable? Only if the code is right next to the classes. Otherwise you have no idea what methods you can call or what the result would be, until the code run and crashed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It just my opinion, but yes more readable and intuitive, because when you call Do it feels like polymorphic call of the class. And I need to say that I also dislike dynamic. Can you tell when this case can crash?